# how to set makeprg in vim when your build system is compiling a copied version of the code

Tags: vim

I have been using the the vim integrated make command to help with my build, fix, repeat cycle at work.  We are in the process of moving to a new build system that I can easily change to using makeprg.

The problem is the new build system copies off the source code to a sandbox location before it builds, so when I get compile errors, vim opens up the copied file.  I end up changing this copied file, and not the actual file in the main code path.

Is some way I can fix this by somehow telling vim what my code base path is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least three strategies you could use to fix this, unfortunately they'll all involve a bit more work than just telling vim a "code base path".  Before choosing one, I'd recommend reading `:help make_makeprg` to get a good sense of the `:make` process "under the hood".

1. Write a shell/perl/ruby/whatever script that filters the output from your build process and rewrites file names from `/sandbox/src/blah.c` to `src/blah.c` or `/sandbox/src` to `src` as appropriate.  Then change `makeprg` to include the filter program when running `make` (in your `.vimrc`, add this: `:set makeprg=make\ \\\|\ filter`). This is probably pretty easy to do, but might be made trickier depending on what exact build system you are using.
2. Change `errorformat` (see `:help errorformat`) to strip off the sandbox prefix for you.  This might not be possible in some cases, depending on the exact output format from your build system.
3. Add a `QuickFixCmdPost` autocommand that will rewrite the file paths in the quickfix window before you begin using `:cnext` and friends.  If you haven't used Vim's autocommand feature before, I would try the other two strategies first.  They are powerful and very useful, but they take some practice to get right.